# sql select records that don't have relation in a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run an SQL query in phpMyAdmin in a MySQL database in order to get records that do not have corresponding records in another table.

E.g.

```
**album**
id, name

**track**
id, album_id, name
```

I need all album records that do not have relative track records.

I have tried

```
SELECT album.id
from album 
WHERE album.id NOT IN (
  SELECT track.album_id 
  FROM track 
  WHERE 1
  GROUP BY track.album_id
)
```

But unfortunately this crashes the MySQL service

I have also tried

```
SELECT a.id FROM album a
INNER JOIN track t
ON a.id = t.album_id
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

but this doesn't work as expected (returns no results)

Comment: May I suggest LEFT JOIN?

Comment: inner join means "where both records are equal". so it won't work.  as Zdavko just posted... you want a left outer join, meaning give me all of this on the left, regardless of what matches on the right

Comment: With LEFT JOIN it crashes (just the same as using the nested SELECT).
Please note, I have 44K tracks and 10K albums. Also tried directly with MySQL command line

Comment: What do you mean "crashes"? Is it just taking a long time to execute? If so, you probably need indices on the id and album_id columns. With the appropriate indices, 44K tracks and 10K albums should be a piece of cake. I have a related pair of tables with 15K and 80K rows respectively and a LEFT JOIN on them takes less than 0.1 seconds.

Comment: track.id is set as Primary, while track.album_id has an index
yes @Kryten what I meant is that it freezes and does not return results (after a good few minutes I manually interrupt the execution)

Comment: @Kryten that was it! I was adding the index key to the wrong database (I have a copy of it). Now runs in 0.03 seconds!!!

Comment: 44K, 10K? That's nothing for MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry well said :)

Answer (score 37):

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM album a
LEFT JOIN track t ON a.id = t.album_id
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use EXISTS to check for the absence of a record in the related table.

```
SELECT album.id
FROM album 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM track 
    WHERE track.album_id = album.id
);
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: not exists is not to be used if you are aiming performance. It is a performance killer.